# how to use drop down menu, taken with javascript as an argument in rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I have several drop-down menus, and I'd like to run a method with selected drop-down's arguments in my controller that will return a result. I will write that result in a span.

This is the js code that I use to get the selected value:

```
$('#segmentation_first_event').on('change',function() {
  var a = document.getElementById("segmentation_first_event");
  alert(a.value);
});
```

What I need to do is use this in my controller.

At first I tried to get the value with `params[:segmentation][:first_event]` but as I figured out later I was trying to get the value before it was submitted to the server, so I basically tried to get something before it existed.

Comment: where you have alert(a.value) you would make an ajax call to your server to get the effect you are looking for...

Comment: Your question is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10080423/passing-javascript-variable-to-ruby-on-rails-controller?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In View

```
$('#segmentation_first_event').on('change',function() {
    var a = $("#segmentation_first_event");
    jQuery.ajax({
        data: 'first_event=' + a,
        dataType: 'script',
        type: 'post',
        url: "/controller_name/action"
    });
});
```

In Controller

```
 def action
   @event = Event.find(params[:first_event])
   #do rest of the stuff

 end
```