# Passing a javascript variable (string) to the controller via ajax - 404

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am trying to pass a javascript variable from my view to my controller via ajax according to the example shown here: [Passing JavaScript variable to ruby-on-rails controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10080423/passing-javascript-variable-to-ruby-on-rails-controller)

my controller "pages_controller.rb" contains the following method:

```
def test_page
    @message= params[:id]
    puts @message
end
```

the respective view "test_page.html.erb" contains javascript with an ajax call which is triggered by clicking a button:

```
<button id="submit_button">Submit Text</button>

<script>
    $("#submit_button").on('click',function(event) {
       var string = "helloWorld";
        $.ajax({
          url: "/test/test_page/?id="+string,
          type: "POST",
          dataType: "text",
          success: function(){
            alert('Saved Successfully');
          },
          error:function(){
           alert('Error');
          }
        });
    });
</script>
```

In routes.rb I have defined the following route:

```
post 'test/test_page/:id', to: 'pages#test_page'
```

However, when I press the button I get the defined error-alert and upon inspecting the browser console I see the following error:

```
jquery.js:11007 POST https://my-website.com/test/test_page/?id=halloWelt 404 (Not Found)
```

But I can see that "rake routes" shows that the following route is defined:

```
POST   /test/test_page/:id(.:format)  pages#test_page
```

I have tried defining another method in the controller and rerouting, however the 404 error still remains. What can I do to fix this 404 error?

Comment: You cannot pass params in url with post request. Use get request. or pass that id with in ajax as data parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking to pass the :id to that route, you can use the following url: `https://my-website.com/test/test_page/halloWelt`. (i.e. `"/test/test_page/" + string`)

I believe in your AJAX, for a POST request, if you want to pass any other data you should explicitly pass in the data like below, rather than via url parameters.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/test/test_page/" + string,
  type: "POST",
  data: { hi: 'there' },
  ...
```

Comment: This works, thank you very much! The AJAX call now gives me a success message! :) I included the message via  <%= @message %> into my view to see the string in the view, but it does not update after the AJAX call. Do you know by chance how to update the view to show the message?

Comment: Yes - you'll need to respond with the message in the controller, and then use this data to populate the field in the AJAX success. Might be worth creating a new question for this, but, in a nutshell: _Controller_: `render json: { message: @message }`, in the success `$('.container-class-name').text(data.message)`. (You'll also need the `data` passed into the success callback's function, i.e. `function(data)...`.) Hope that helps!